# CheckBox in java code

Tags: java, swing, boolean, jcheckbox

i can't seem to determine what my code is missing.. please help.. i want to create a check box on my code but i can't get it right.. this is from another frame, it's not my main program..

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Start extends JFrame implements ItemListener
{
    JLabel num1 = new JLabel("1) Is Internet Explorer a web browser?");
    JCheckBox true = new JCheckBox("True", false);
    JCheckBox false = new JCheckBox("False", false);
    String output, insChosen;

    public Start()
    {
        setBounds(100,100,500,400);
        setResizable(false);
        num1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC,12));
        add(num1);
        true.addItemListener(this);
        false.addItemListener(this);
        add(true);
        add(false);
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent check)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be using a LayoutManager. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html

Comment: Also, using JCheckBoxes for answering a Yes/No question is typically not appropriate. Consider using JRadioButtons in a ButtonGroup. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`true` and `false` is Java keyword. You can't use keyword as identifier. Please follow the Java  identifier naming convention. For example:

```
JCheckBox trueCheck = new JCheckBox("True", false);
JCheckBox falseCheck = new JCheckBox("False", false);
```

Comment: i have changed the names but only one check box is appearing when i try to run it, my JLabel isn't appearing

Comment: @user3360927, The default layout of JFrame is BorderLaout. If you did not specify position than it take a component at center position. So use a layout manager with `JFrame` to see all elements.

Comment: For example, use BoxLayout or GridLayout.